# Can't figure out preorder traversal

Tags: java

```
 public void traverse(ListItem root) {
        //preorder traversal - going to left childs first
        ListItem focusNode;
        ListItem parentNode;
        if (root == null) {
            System.out.println("Empty tree");
        } else {
            if (root.leftLink != null) {
                System.out.println(root.getValue());
                parentNode = root;
                while (parentNode.leftLink != null) {
                    focusNode = parentNode.leftLink;
                    System.out.println(focusNode.getValue());
                    parentNode = focusNode.leftLink;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So this is what I got so far. I think this is able to print out all the nodes going down the left of the tree but I haven't figured out a way to for the lack of better term jump back to previous entries and test whether there is a left node, if not go to a right node.

Comment: You could try recursion or a stack.

Answer (score 1):

Using recursion you could do something like this:

```
public void traverse(ListItem node) {
    if (node== null) {
        System.out.println("Empty tree");
    } else {
        if (node.leftLink != null) {
            traverse( node.leftLink );
        }
        if (node.rightLink != null) {
            traverse( node.rightLink );
        }

        System.out.println( node.getValue());               
    }
}
```

This will check whether the left child exists and recursively calls the method for the left subtree (child) then does the same for the right child. After all children have been printed the node's own value will be printed.

Example:

Assume the following tree

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 / \   \
D   E    F
```

Calling `traverse(A)` will result in the folling output:

```
D
E
B
F
C
A
```

Comment: I havent researched recursions but I saw similar code on youtube and i get that you must check if theres a left and right subtree and then use a preorder method but then something like: traverse( node.leftLink ); has no implementation behind it that follows a preorder method...

Comment: @GiancarloGatti I don't get your comment but basically you call `traverse` again for the left and then the right child. The call stack will handle the order for you.

Comment: If you remove the necessity to print out "Empty tree", then you can eliminate one of the two checks for null that you're performing in your recursive algorithm.  Traditionally, you check when called not prior to calling.

Comment: @Neil you're right, I'd do that myself but wanted to keep the code as close to the original as possible.